# How can I add a class attribute to an HTML element generated by MVC's HTML Helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

ASP.NET MVC can generate HTML elements using HTML Helpers, for example `@Html.ActionLink()`, `@Html.BeginForm()` and so on.

I know I can specify form attributes by creating an [anonymous object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) and pass that object for the (fourth in this case) `htmlAttributes` parameter where specifying an `id` for the element:

```
Html.BeginForm("Foo", "Bar", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm"})
```

But what about the `class` attribute? Obviously this does not work:

```
Html.BeginForm("Foo", "Bar", FormMethod.Post, new { class = "myclass"})
```

As that just throws random syntax errors when my view is requested, because it expects something else after encountering the C# keyword `class`.

I've also tried:

```
new { _class = "myclass"}
```

and

```
new { class_ = "myclass"}
```

But they also did not work, as the [underscores get replaced by dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108943/actionlink-htmlattributes).

I know that I can just as well write the HTML elements by hand or wrap the form inside a `<div class="myClass">`, but I'd still be interested to know how it is supposed to be done.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

In order to create an anonymous type (or any type) with a property that has a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(v=vs.110).aspx) as its name in C#, you can prepend the property name with an at sign, `@`:

```
Html.BeginForm("Foo", "Bar", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myclass"})
```

For VB.NET [this syntax would be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444495/how-do-i-apply-a-css-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc) accomplished using the dot, `.`, which in that language is default syntax for [*all* anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384767.aspx):

```
Html.BeginForm("Foo", "Bar", FormMethod.Post, new with { .class = "myclass" })
```

Comment: The parser is not smart enough, IMO, if it needs that hint given the context it's in at that point in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Current best practice in CSS development is to create more general selectors with modifiers that can be applied as widely as possible throughout the web site. I would try to avoid defining separate styles for individual page elements.

If the purpose of the CSS class on the `<form/>` element is to control the style of elements within the form, you could add the class attribute the existing `<fieldset/>` element which encapsulates any form by default in web pages generated by ASP.NET MVC. A CSS class on the form is rarely necessary.

Comment: You are certainly right, however this case is different. I was looking for a way to specify metadata for a few jquery plugins. This is usually done by misusing the class attribute.

Comment: You can suggest best practices, but if I have a template that uses css on a form, I'm not going to go butcher the template to make it "correct".  Reality is, a customer isn't going to pay more because you did the right thing by css...

Comment: @ChristianPayne They might be forced to pay more in the future because you didn't.

Comment: I down-voted this response because it does not answer the question. A more appropriate answer would answer the question first then give best practice guidance.