# How do I apply a CSS class to Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html-helper

I'm building an *ASP.NET MVC* application, using *VB.NET* and I'm trying to apply a css class to a `Html.ActionLink` using the code:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {@class = "tab" })%>
```

But when I run the code I receive the below error:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30988: Type or 'With' expected.

I'm new to *MVC* and really haven't much of a clue what I'm doing so I can't see what's wrong there as I'm using code based of an example elsewhere.

Comment: There is no such a signature for Html.ActionLink method with (string, string, string, object).

Comment: Is there anyway to do this *without* using an anonymous class?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", MyRouteValObj, new with {.class = "tab" })%>
```

In VB.net you set an anonymous type using

```
new with {.class = "tab" }
```

and, as other point out, your third parameter should be an object (could be an anonymous type, also).

Answer (score 161):

@ewomack has a great answer for C#, unless you don't need extra object values.  In my case, I ended up using something similar to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteList", "List", new object { },
new { @class = "delete"})
```

Comment: If you don't need the route values you can also pass `null` as the 4th argument: `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteList", "List", null,
new { @class = "delete"})`

Answer (score 60):

In C# it also works with a null as the 4th parameter.

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Front Page", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "MenuButtons" })
```

Comment: This is Helpful because when you add null, you are getting a standard and clean url request

Answer (score 35):

This syntax worked for me in MVC 3 with Razor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteList", "List", new { ID = item.ID, ListID = item.id }, new {@class= "delete"})
```

Answer (score 21):

This works for MVC 5

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

Comment: For using in a MVC 5 ActionLink with parameters: @Html.ActionLink("Text of the link", "Action", "Controller name", new { myParam = "XXX" }, new { @style = "color:black" } )

Comment: @mggSoft YES!! This worked for me using MVC 5. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "ContactUs", "Home", Nothing, New With {.class = "link"})%>
```

This will assign css class "link" to the Contact Us.

This will generate following HTML :

```
<a class="link" href="www.domain.com/Home/ContactUs">Contact Us</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work , tested in MVC core 6

- Good code readability
- it allow you set other html attributes , eg i use target attribute to open new tab
- it allow you set class value , eg i use bootstrap convert hyperlink to button
- it allow you apply custom inline style

  ```
       @Html.ActionLink(
               linkText: "Button\Hyperlink Label",
               actionName: "Index",
               controllerName: "Home",
               routeValues: new { Id = @item.ToString() },
               htmlAttributes: new { target = "_blank",@class="btn" , @style="background-color:lightblue;margin: 10px 30px;"})
  ```