# Apply a css style to a html helper

Tags: html, css, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Asp.net application with razor view engine

I'd like to apply a css style in `Html.ActionLink`. So I tried to change this :

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Espace propriétaire du terrain <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

To this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Espace propriétaire du terrain ", "About", "Home",null, new {  @style="class:dropdown-toggle;data-toggle:dropdown; role:button; aria-expanded:false" })
```

But the style isn't applied and I get this as a source html code

```
<a href="/Home/About" style="class:dropdown-toggle;data-toggle:dropdown; role:button; aria-expanded:false">Espace propriétaire du terrain </a>
```

So  I need to know :

1. Why this happens?
2. How can I fix my code?

Comment: It needs to be `new { @class="dropdown-toggle", data_toggle="dropdown", role="button", aria_expanded="false" }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I apply a CSS class to Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444495/how-do-i-apply-a-css-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Attributes.Add("style", "class = dropdown-toggle;");  not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate, but with a quick look i can tell that "@style" means you're attempting to set the style attribute. In order to set the class attribute you'd  have to use "@class"

Comment: @larssy1 The style attribute would just be `style="[CSS HERE]"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify your HTML attributes as multiple values within your anonymous `new {}` object:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Espace propriétaire du terrain ", "About", "Home",null, new {  @class="dropdown", data_toggle="dropdown", role="button", aria_expanded = "false" })
```

In your example you are just adding and setting the value for the `style` attribute, when you want multiple attributes within the generated HTML tag.

NB:

- The helper will automatically change your underscores to dashes for
  the attribute names.
- The `@` symbol should be prepended to any field names in the
  anonymous object that match exactly a reserved word in C#.