# Li element not remaining selected on the click of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created an `li` item with `Html.ActionLink` which renders ultimately as an anchor tag. I have applied CSS for hover and it works perfectly fine.

Now I need to highlight the `li` box when I click on it. I have used jQuery but that doesn't seem to work. I have checked the debugger tools and there doesn't seem to be any errors. So I guess it's the case that the class is not getting applied. I'm Not sure what the problem is. Please see my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navcontainer ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.highlightMenu').removeClass('highlightMenu');
    $(this).addClass('highlightMenu');
  });
});
```

```css
#navcontainer ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-top: 40px;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

#navcontainer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*height: 50px;
        width:150px;*/
  border: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-left: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-right: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-top: 5px solid #009ddc;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #24387f !important;
}

#navcontainer li a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #009ddc;
}

#navcontainer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .2em 3em 1em 1em;
  color: #24387f !important;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlightMenu {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #009ddc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left text-center">

        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Team Management", "Team", "Admin", null, null)</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Management", "UserProfile", "Admin", null, null)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in the snippet.

Comment: Are you talking of hover. What I want is when I click the  li item it should remain hightlighted. When I run the snippet I dont see that happening

Comment: Do you intend to load a new page when the link is clicked?

Comment: I get an error Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. Hence cant see the button

Comment: Well, yes. That's because the URL doesn't exist on the Stack Overflow server - it's an example.

Comment: No. The menu is in the partial view .I am calling this partial view when I load Team view and UserProfile view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137364/discussion-between-tom-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: Hi Rory Is it working if you put a dummy page at your end ?

Answer (score 6):

1. You should read about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity): your `.highlightMenu {}` selector will never be applied, because `.#navcontainer ul li {}` selector is more specific. Prefer [Class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), check out [BEM methodology](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/).
2. From MDN about [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception):

   > Using `!important`, however, is **bad practice** and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural [cascading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) in your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with the `!important` rule are applied to the same element, the declaration with a greater specificity will be applied.
3. If you want to set `.highlightMenu` class to `<li>` when clicking on `<a>`, you could use jQuery [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) for it.
4. If you add list items dynamically, you could use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

I've cleaned your code and rewritten it in [BEM-style](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/) with the fixes, check out:

```js
$('.nav').on('click', '.nav__link', function() {
    $('.nav__item_selected').removeClass('nav__item_selected');
    $(this).closest('.nav__item').addClass('nav__item_selected');
});
```

```css
.nav {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

    .nav__item {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 5px solid #009ddc;
        padding: 0;
        background: #fff;
        color: #24387f;
    }
    
    .nav__item:hover, .nav__item_selected {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #009ddc;
    }
    
    .nav__link {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0.2em 3em 1em 1em;
        color: #24387f;
        font-size: larger;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav__item">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Team Management</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">User Management</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This example works but I need to get the html.action link working. The html.action link is the preferred approach in MVC and it is not recommended to use the a tag directly and have a url manually written.

Comment: @Tom yes, I understand, I used `<a>` only to make the snippet works, because in your snippet it doesn't really work, `@Html.ActionLink` there — simply plain text. Create the working snippet please, for example, here — https://dotnetfiddle.net, I'll try to help you.

Comment: @Tom also, you could simply try to use my HTML/CSS/jQuery code and change my `<a>` elements to your `@Html.ActionLink`s, but add CSS class `nav__link` to them. See [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444495/how-do-i-apply-a-css-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc) about adding CSS class to `@Html.ActionLink`.

Comment: In your code , you have set class for both li and a tag. I just have an html.action inside the li. How do i set the class for the a tag as the a tag is generated at run time

Comment: @Tom yeah, you're right. Then you could use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Check out my updated answer (I've changed only the first line in Javascript).

Comment: Hey Sergey updated the post. Cant understand why it is not working. God the code quite similar to yours. Even the alert method doesnt fire

Comment: Now I may not need event delegation as I am able to apply the class to the anchor tag as well. What was your previous code. Could you test my code and see if it works at your end

Comment: @Tom check it out — https://jsfiddle.net/8nd3sb95/2/. I took your code and changed: you forgot to add `adminnav` CSS class to `<ul>` element, also I added [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to disable default link action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137755/discussion-between-tom-and-sergey-denisov).

Answer (score 2):

I have changed a little bit your CSS and your script.
Now the new class is added correctly to the elements.

Please, have a look at https://fiddle.jshell.net/mh2gqmju/

All the best.

Comment: I tried putting an alert in the click function and it doesnt fire.

Comment: It doesnt seem to add the class on the click event

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is targeting the hyperlink, while you need to highlight the list-item only.

But now, if you correct your code to target the list-item in the list in place of the hyperlinks, you won't be able to see changes on the screen. (You would be able to see the classes toggling in the browser's developer tools though, obviously).

Why so? Because the hyperlink inside the list-item is hiding all the changes you want to see when the list-item gets clicked.

I added one more CSS property to the `.highlightMenu` in order to make you notice the changes.

See yourself:

- JavaScript is modified to target the list-items, not hyperlinks within the `ul` in `#navcontainer`
- `.highlightMenu` carries one extra CSS property now (outline), to notice the style changes on the click event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navcontainer ul li').click(function() {
    $('.highlightMenu').removeClass('highlightMenu');
    $(this).addClass('highlightMenu');
  });
});
```

```css
#navcontainer ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-top: 40px;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

#navcontainer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*height: 50px;
        width:150px;*/
  border: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-left: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-right: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-top: 5px solid #009ddc;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #24387f !important;
}

#navcontainer li a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #009ddc;
}

#navcontainer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .2em 3em 1em 1em;
  color: #24387f !important;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlightMenu {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #009ddc;
outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left text-center">

        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Team Management", "Team", "Admin", null, null)</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Management", "UserProfile", "Admin", null, null)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and easy hack which allows elements to respond when clicked but which does not require any scripting:

- add the `tabindex="0"` attribute to the element
- apply styles to the element, using the `:focus` pseudo-class

**Working Example:**

```css
li {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
text-align: center;
vertical-align: top;
}

li:nth-of-type(1):hover {
color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

li:nth-of-type(1):focus {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(0, 127, 0);
}

li:nth-of-type(2):hover {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

li:nth-of-type(2):focus {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(127, 127, 255);
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li tabindex="0">
Red on<br />Hover
<br /><br />
Green on<br />Click
</li>

<li tabindex="0">
Yellow on<br />Hover
<br /><br />
Blue on<br />Click</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added the tabindex = 0 to my li element. The hover works however the focus doesnt. Dont know the reason why

Comment: I put a different colour for the focus to test. So It does change when i click but it gets to the original colour later

Answer (score 1):

The reason I believe your code might not be working is this line

```js
$('#navcontainer ul li a').click(function()
```

You have included the anchor **"a"** on the selector eventhough you want to be highlighting the **"li"** tag. It should be more like this:

```js
$('#navcontainer ul li').click(function()
```

I have checked this on fiddle.jshell and it seems to fix the problem.

Comment: i tried this and it foesnt seem to work. Can you share the fiddle soloution

Comment: Here is the fiddle solution.

Comment: Here is the fiddle solution.
https://fiddle.jshell.net/mh2gqmju/3/

I have added a few things to the code to prevent the default behaviour of clicking the link. 

This solution has "a" on the selector. If you go to the solution and remove the "a" tag this should work as intended

Comment: Are you sure it works as I can see only the hover working which it does in my case. I am looking at setting the listitem as selected when clicked

Comment: I tried it again. Very close but still need to achieve the desired result. I have noticed a pattern. If i click on between one of the items then one of the items get selected. But if i directly select on any one item then it doesnt. So when I inspect the area between the two elements it is list element i believe. So what I am suspecting is that only on click of the li it happens .How to do the same for the anchor tag too

Answer (score 1):

```
<code>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '#navcontainer ul li a', function () {
     $('.highlightMenu').removeClass('highlightMenu');
     $(this).addClass('highlightMenu');
  });`enter code here`
});

</code>
<br>
Please use the above added code i believe it's good for query..
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct ... You just need to modify your `.css` a bit.

**Old css :-**

```
     padding: .2em 3em 1em 1em;
```

**Changed to :-**

```
padding: 2px 1px 1px 1px ;
```

**See the screen shot**
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navcontainer ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.highlightMenu').removeClass('highlightMenu');
    $(this).addClass('highlightMenu');
  });
});
```

```css
#navcontainer ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-top: 40px;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

#navcontainer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*height: 50px;
        width:150px;*/
  border: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-left: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-right: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-top: 5px solid #009ddc;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #24387f !important;
}

#navcontainer li a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #009ddc;
}

#navcontainer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 2px 1px 1px 1px ; /*padding: .2em 3em 1em 1em;*/
  color: #24387f !important;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlightMenu {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #009ddc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left text-center">

        <li><a> Team Management </a></li>
        <li><a>User Management</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tom - please check the above answer

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to css and jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navcontainer ul li').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // Remove this line please, just for this example
    $(this).addClass('highlightMenu').siblings().removeClass('highlightMenu');
  });
});
```

```css
#navcontainer ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-top: 40px;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

#navcontainer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*height: 50px;
        width:150px;*/
  border: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-left: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-right: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #009ddc;
  border-top: 5px solid #009ddc;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #24387f !important;
}

#navcontainer li:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #009ddc;
}

#navcontainer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .2em 3em 1em 1em;
  color: #24387f !important;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navcontainer ul li.highlightMenu {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #009ddc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navcontainer">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left text-center">
    <li><a href="/admin/team">Team Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/userprofile">User Management</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```