# Adding a class to Html.ActionLink doesn't get added as class, but instead as a GET parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I honestly can't see why on earth this doesn't work, but here it goes:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" }, null)
```

This should produce:

```
<a href="/Home/About" class="nav-link">About</a>
```

But instead it produces:

```
<a href="/Home/About?class=nav-link">About</a>
```

All the annotations for adding a class to an ActionLink, tells me to do it that way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you remove `, null`? The overload that takes 4 arguments should be the correct one. Try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196582/1661209

Comment: What version of mvc are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply a CSS class to Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444495/how-do-i-apply-a-css-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, apparently it's supposed to be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new object {}, new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

Weird.

Comment: `null` instead of `new object {}` should work as well.

Comment: @Max Definitely yeah.