# ActionLink htmlAttributes with hyphens

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, actionlink, html.actionlink

This works

```
<a href="@Url.Action("edit", "markets", new { id = 1 })" 
            data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Edit</a>
```

But this doesn't. Why?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", "markets", new { id = 1 }, new {@class="ui-btn-right", data-icon="gear"})
```

It seems you can't pass something like `data-icon="gear"` into `htmlAttributes`?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The problem is that your anonymous object property `data-icon` has an invalid name. C# properties cannot have dashes in their names. There are two ways you can get around that:

Use an underscore instead of dash (MVC will automatically replace the underscore with a dash in the emitted HTML):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", "markets",
      new { id = 1 },
      new {@class="ui-btn-right", data_icon="gear"})
```

Use the overload that takes in a dictionary:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", "markets",
      new { id = 1 },
      new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "ui-btn-right" }, { "data-icon", "gear" } });
```

Comment: The underscore does not seem to work with `Ajax.ActionLink` helpers

Comment: The underscore trick sounds really strange, what if you want an underscore in your html attribute?

Comment: @MichielReyers you could use the overload that takes in the Dictionary

Comment: .net Core Tag Helpers destroy all these problems - hi from the future.

Answer (score 27):

Replace the desired hyphen with an underscore; it will automatically be rendered as a hyphen:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", "markets",
    new { id = 1 },
    new {@class="ui-btn-right", data_icon="gear"})
```

becomes:

```
<form action="markets/Edit/1" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="gear" .../>
```

Answer (score -6):

```
@Html.ActionLink("display name", "action", "Contorller"
    new { id = 1 },Html Attribute=new {Attribute1="value"})
```