# ActionLink with multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I want to create a URL like `/?name=Macbeth&year=2011` with my `ActionLink` which I have tried doing like so:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("View Details", "Details", "Performances", new { name = item.show }, new { year = item.year })%>
```

but it doesn't work. How do I do this?

Comment: Best asnwer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225786/passing-multiple-parameters-from-url-to-html-actionlink

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The overload you are using makes the `year` value end up in the html attributes of the link (check your rendered source).

The overload signature looks like this:

```
MvcHtmlString HtmlHelper.ActionLink(
    string linkText, 
    string actionName, 
    string controllerName, 
    object routeValues, 
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

You need to put both your route values in to the `RouteValues` dictionary like this:

```
Html.ActionLink(
    "View Details", 
    "Details", 
    "Performances", 
    new { name = item.show, year = item.year }, 
    null
)
```

Comment: And how to generate path like `/Macbeth/2011`?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Mikael Östberg answer add something like this in your global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "View Details",
    "Performances/Details/{name}/{year}",
    new {
        controller ="Performances",
        action="Details", 
        name=UrlParameter.Optional,
        year=UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

then in your controller

```
// the name of the parameter must match the global.asax route    
public action result Details(string name, int year)
{
    return View(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mikael Östberg answer and just in case people need to know how it does with html attr. Here is another example, reference from [ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110661/1661691)

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Details", 
"Details", 
"Performances", 
  new { name = item.show, year = item.year }, 
  new {@class="ui-btn-right", data_icon="gear"})


@Html.ActionLink("View Details", 
"Details", 
"Performances", new RouteValueDictionary(new {id = 1}),new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "ui-btn-test" }, { "data-icon", "gear" } })
```