# @Html.ActionLink not linking to Account/Login, Account/Register, Account/Logout properly. Not sure what I'm missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to use the @Html.ActionLink to create a navigation bar for my web app. It works fine for my Home, Blogs, Posts links but it isn't working properly for my Register/Login/Logout links. Not sure what I'm missing. Am I supposed to make a Helper Method or something?

```js
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using SpareCodeBlog.Models
@inject SignInManager<BlogUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<BlogUser> UserManager

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
        var user = UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
    }

    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + user.FirstName + user.LastName + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Account", Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = ""}))
            @*<form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })"><button type="submit">Logout</button></form>*@
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, new { id = "loginLink", @class = "nav-link mr-0" })
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, new { id = "registerLink", @class = "nav-link mr-0" })
        </li>
    }
```

```html
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-toggle-pills">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <!-- Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action Method", "Controller", route value, htmlArguments)-->
                            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link mr-0" })
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Blogs", "Index", "Blogs", null, new { @class = "nav-link mr-0" })
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Posts", "Index", "Posts", null, new { @class = "nav-link mr-0" })
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                        </li>
                    </ul><!-- / navbar-nav -->
                </div><!-- / navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- / container -->
        </nav><!-- / navbar-pills -->
```

Comment: What do you mean for `it isn't working properly for my Register/Login/Logout links`?Does it do not generate the correct url or the generated url is 404?Please share what is the result you want and what is the result you get now.

Comment: Hi @KenanBjelosevic, any updates about this case? If you specify the area as I shared in my post, does it work for you?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't replicate the issue anymore. I was just testing a few things out and am now working on a different project. Thanks for trying to help. If I remember correctly, it was throwing a 404 error as it wasn't sure where I was pointing it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
  @Html.ActionLink(
                        "View Details",
                        "Login",
                        "Register",
                        new { id = "Logout" }
                        )
```

for more information please visit:
[Passing multiple parameters from url to html.actionlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225786/passing-multiple-parameters-from-url-to-html-actionlink/13225835)

Answer (score 0):

> it isn't working properly for my Register/Login/Logout links. Not sure what I'm missing.

The Identity Razor Class Library exposes endpoints with the `Identity` area, to generate links to these Identity related pages, please specify the area like below.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", new { area = "Identity" }, new { id = "registerLink", @class = "nav-link mr-0" })
```

*The area route added to `startup`*

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "MyArea",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Test Result

[image]