# How to use a standard html link to call MVC controller method with parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If you can't use an ActionLink or AJAX and want to call a parameterised controller method from a simple/standard HTML link.

Comment: This is a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593759/actionlink-with-multiple-parameters

Comment: I didn't quite understand if this is a question or you have found some solution that are posting here. If this is a question, please make it a question. If not, StackOverflow is not the right place.

Comment: @Darin I wanted to post a question and answer it myself but as a new user I am unable to do that until 8 hours have elapsed. Feel free to answer it with the given code and I will edit.

Comment: Right click on the web page .see the `source code` in the browser.

Comment: As per the title: How to use a standard html link to call MVC controller method with parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can send parameter with 2 method:

1.

```
<a href='/Controller/Method?param=paramValue&anotherParam=anotherParamValue'>link text</a>
```

without "/" after method and use "?" for parameter.

2.

```
<a href='/Controller/Method/paramValue/anotherParamValue'>link text</a>
```

Use "/" without "?" for each parameter and just send value. No parameter name. 
Be careful for parameter order

Is this what you want?

Comment: I wanted to help anyone with the same problem by asking a question and answering it but this will do! Thanks, will edit my question.

Comment: Just 404s for me. Quadruple checked the URL but it just won't do it.