# How to access a UserID when a hyperlink is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is the hyperlinked code I am generating to show a list of merchants:

```
    <td>

        @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MerchantName).ToHtmlString(), "ViewMerchant", "Merchants")
    </td>
```

What I would like for it to do is to take me to a new page where it shows just the information on the merchant selected (address, webaddress, etc), so a ViewMerchant page in my Merchants View folder.

Can I grab the MerchantID in this ActionLink?  If so how would that code look in the above ActionLink?

Secondly in the View Merchants page if anyone could link me to a site that would explain how to build that so the page gets populated with the merchant info would be ideal.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593759/actionlink-with-multiple-parameters) Shows how to pass parameters to your ActionLink.

Comment: Ok that got me looking in the right direction, so I found this: new { id=item.MerchantId }, as a sample parameter that would seem to work.

What I see as the problem is that I will have a array of menu items attached to the merchant, so wondering if that Menu will also display (which is what I am aiming to do ultimately).

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying in your comment, please edit and update your question with more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `MerchantID` as a route value as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "ViewMerchant", "Merchants", new { id = item.MerchantID }, null )
```

Where `ViewMerchant` is the name of your action instide `MerchantsController`

And here is a small sample to your details action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Merchant merchant = db.Merchants.Find(id);

    return View(merchant);
}
```

Of course, you should use `ViewModels` instead of passing your model to the view. But that's another matter on which you can find many information online. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) is one link to start reading about it.