# Razor Html helper Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view in ASP.NET MVC4 and it has the following code which starts an HTML form:

```
      @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
```

Now i need to give this form an id="login" and a class="loginform". How do I specify such HTML parameters to the Html.BeginForm class?

Also: where can I find an API or documentation on all the HTML helper functions which explains all of the parameters and the details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in code:

`@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "login", @class = "loginform" }))`

See information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this page on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper_members(v=vs..90).aspx. It lists controls generation methods in Extension Methods section. You can find information about creating *form* element with attributes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714(v=vs.90).aspx and here: [How can I add a class attribute to an HTML element generated by MVC's HTML Helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879266/how-can-i-add-a-class-attribute-via-html-beginform).