# How to implement bootstrap in an actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I would like to implement bootstrap in the following actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "DepartmentView", "Department", null, 
 new { @style="text-transform:capitalize;" })
```

Comment: What is "implement bootstrap in an actionlink"? What does this code do? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @CodeCaster i want to change the css of "Create new" link with icon and color.

Comment: Do you mean you want to apply a CSS class to the action link?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for my english @CodeCaster I'm not able to use #Html.Bootstrap.

Comment: Then see for example [How can I add a class attribute via Html.BeginForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879266/how-can-i-add-a-class-attribute-via-html-beginform). Add a `@class` property to the `htmlAttributes` parameter. So change `new { @style=...` to `new { @class="yourClass", style=...`.

Comment: oh yea ! Now i get it !! Thanks !!  CodeCaster @Francis

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "FooAction", "FooController", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```