# can i insert html code and Razor code in same cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I insert html designing/code with this Razor CSHTML code in same page?

```
@model project_final.Models.Bike
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <fieldset>
    @<legend>Bike</legend>
    @<div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Color)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Color)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Color)
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
}

<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: What do you mean _"html designing/code"_? What code are you referring to. And why do you have the `@` symbol in `@<legend>Bike</legend>` and `@<div class="editor-label">`?

Comment: Did you try it? Was the answer yes or no?  This can be worked out very simply just by trying it and observing what happens.

Comment: Razor is just a markup syntax for your html.
You can definitely embedd HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Just beware of what is the **code** that need to have @ in Razor engine, and what is **html tag** don't need the @ like what @Stephen Muecke mentioned.
@Bike does not need the @ in front of it because  is html tag. Or I make a simple statement that

> @ **never** stick with <, if you found **@<** in your ASP.Net View, it must be a
>   **mistake**

Read the [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)), may be you can know more things about Razor.

By the way , you might need to read the post [How can I add a class attribute to an HTML element generated by MVC's HTML Helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879266/how-can-i-add-a-class-attribute-to-an-html-element-generated-by-mvcs-html-helpe) to modified the class of the HTML helper such as @Html.LabelFor

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
```